# Didn't understand relationship 'param' in field path

Tags: apex

When I Execute, the below code

```
Loan__c param = (Loan__c)Value;
        List<SObject> loans = [Select Name,Amount__c, Application__c,
                        Business_Impact__c,Borrower__c,Disbursed_Amount__c,Disbursed_Date__c,
                        Disbursed_User__c,Fund__c, LastModifiedById,Notes__c,Paid_Date__c,
                        Product__c,Rating__c,Reason__c,CreatedById,Status__c from Loan__c
                        where 
                        (param.Name = Null or Name = :param.Name)
```

I got below Error

> Didn't understand relationship 'param' in field path. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r'
>   after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or th
>   describe call for the appropriate names

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your where clause. param.Name cannot be used in SOQL directly. Also Name is required field so you don't need this

```
where (param.Name = Null or Name = :param.Name)
```

do this

```
where Name = :param.Name
```